# Is "Record" Deprecated in Rhino Mocks

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

The latest version of Rhino mocks supports Arrange, Act Assert methodology.  Does that mean that the record method that it used in previous version is deprecated?

I thought it was (deprecated), but as I was reading "The Art of Unit Testing" he uses the Record method when he introduces Rhino Mocks.  So now I am not so sure....

Any one know for sure?

---

UPDATE: OK, I need to read the whole chapter before I get all upset about how he is doing things.  In section 5.8 he covers AAA syntax.  Still, my question remains, which is preferred now: AAA or record?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Record when you are using AAA syntax. Could you paste the link to "The Art of Unit Testing"? A lot of the documentation hasn't been updated after introduction of AAA syntax.

EDIT: I prefer the AAA syntax, because it reads better. It seems also easier to set some constraints on arguments (especially the Arg<...>.Match), you don't have to remember about running ReplayAll, etc.

Comment: I am just reading the book.  Maybe I was not clear, but he is not trying to mix the two, he just favors the record method over the AAA syntax.  I thought the AAA syntax had replaced the record style.  But he is using it In chapter 5.

Comment: See my update, he covers AAA later in the chapter.  I should have read the whole chapter...